# What is the difference between project leader and postdoc at Max Planck?

Tags: postdocs, career-path, job, germany

I can't find info on the *project leader* position at the Max Planck Institute. I know it is not the same as *group leader*. Is there a difference between project leader and postdoc at Max Planck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Max Planck, but Fraunhofer - I am not sure if the model is similar, but maybe it helps nevertheless.

Here, a group leader is a career step / leadership position: someone who leads a group of scientists working on a specific topic. A working group will work on many different projects. In the group, there are PhD candidates, postdocs, and also master graduates that do not plan on obtaining a PhD.

A project leader is anyone from the group who holds the main responsibility for a project, in some cases that will be the group leader, but in others it will be the PhD candidates or the postdocs.